# Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k(X)-\lambda_k(Y)|\leq\|X-Y\|_1$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, matrix-norms

$X,Y$ are $n\times n$ Hermitian matrices. $\lambda_k(X)$ denotes the $k$th largest eigenvalue of $X$. Prove that $\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k(X)-\lambda_k(Y)|\leq\|X-Y\|_1$. (Here $\|X-Y\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^n|\lambda_k(X-Y)|$)

Attempts: Using Spectral decomposition we can write $X-Y$ as $P-Q$, where $P,Q\succeq 0$, and $\|X-Y\|_1=tr(P)+tr(Q)$, but I don't know how to associate with $\lambda_k(X)-\lambda_k(Y)$.

Comment: Please clarify the meaning of $\|\cdot\|_1$. Some authors use it to denote the trace norm (a.k.a. nuclear norm or Schatten $1$-norm) and some others use it to denote the induced $1$-norm.

Comment: @user1551 I updated.

Comment: why do you write $\|X-Y\|_{S_1}=tr(P)+tr(Q)$? If $P\succ Q \succ 0$ then this is false.

Comment: @user8675309 I guess $PQ=0,$ so $P-Q$ is the Hahn decomposition of $X-Y.$

Comment: @user8675309 $X-Y$ is Hermitian, $P=\sum\lambda_i x_ix_i^*$, where  $\lambda_i$ are positve eigenvalues of $X-Y$.

Comment: @qmww987 This should be explicitly stated in your OP.  When working with majorization problems [which this one is] it is common to observe the same relationship holds for e.g. $X':= X+\delta I$ and $Y'=Y+\delta I$  for arbitrary $\delta\in \mathbb R$ so we may as well assume $X, Y \succeq \mathbf 0$ (hence without your conditions stated: a choice of $P=X$ and $Q=Y$) and directly applying what you wrote gives an error.  Unfortunately showing the majorization is rather involved here.

Comment: @user8675309 I mean there exists (instead of for all) $P,Q$ such that $tr(P)+tr(Q)=||X-Y||_1$